# Node.js: Continuous execution from settimeout when expecting node to do nothing until settimeout interval over

Tags: node.js, settimeout

I'm writing a notifier for 3 deal of the day websites in node. I go and parse the body of the webpage to grab the details. In the details there is a timer for the how long the deal will last. I'm reading that timer and trying to use setTimeout/setInterval to set when the function should execute again. However the function calls are continuous instead of waiting.

Pseudo code of what I'm doing:

```
var getData = function(url) {
request(url, function(err, resp, body){                                                                                      
       if(err)   throw err; 
//process the body getting the deal information and timer
setTimeout(getData(url),timer*1000);
}

getData(url1);
getData(url2);
getData(url3);
```

Full code [here](https://github.com/nickklosterman/BashScripts/tree/master/DealScrapers/BackcountryWebsites/node/pageScraper).

I want the program to run, continually calling itself with the new timeouts for the webpages.

I'm a Node.js newbie so I'm guessing I'm getting tripped up with the async nature of things.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
more simply :

```
var hello = function(){
console.log("hello");
setTimeout(hello(),25000);
}

hello();
```

prints out hello continuously instead of hello every 2.5s. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is evident in your `hello` example, so lets take a look at that:

```
var hello = function(){
    console.log("hello");
    setTimeout(hello(),25000);
}

hello();
```

In particular this line: `setTimeout(hello(),25000);`. Perhaps you are expecting that to call `hello` after a 25 second timeout? Well it doesn't, it calls `hello` immediately, (that's what `hello()` does in Javascript, and there is nothing special about `setTimeout`), and then it passes the return value of `hello()` to `setTimeout`, which would only make sense if `hello()` returned another function. Since `hello` recursively calls itself unconditionally, it doesn't ever return, and `setTimeout` will never be called. It's similar to doing the following:

```
function hello() {
  return doSomething(hello());
}
```

Is it clear why `doSomething` will never be called?

If you want to pass a function to `setTimeout`, just pass the function itself, don't call it and pass the return value: `setTimeout(hello, 25000);`.

Your fixed code:

```
var getData = function(url) {
  request(url, function(err, resp, body){                                                                                      
    if(err)   throw err; 
    //process the body getting the deal information and timer
    setTimeout(getData, timer*1000, url);
  });
};

getData(url1);
getData(url2);
getData(url3);
```

Noticed that I passed the argument for `getData` as a third argument to `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks. That would've taken me forever to realize that I was executing the function and not passing it in. I didn't realize that in effect I was passing the return value of `hello()` as the callback of setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is 'request' is being run as soon as getData is called.  Do you want `getData` to be the function you call to start the timer, or the one that loads the data?

```
var getData = function(url) {
    function doRequest(url) {
        request(url, function(err, resp, body) {                                                                                      
        if(err)   throw err; 
        //process the body getting the deal information and timer
    }
    setTimeout(doRequest(url),timer*1000);
}

getData(url1);
getData(url2);
getData(url3);
```

What you want is 'setTimeout' to point to a function (or anonymous function/callback) that you run after the timer expires.  As you originally wrote, `getData` was immediately calling `request` (and then calling `getData` *again* after your timer)

Comment: Right, I needed to 'seed' the program with the first iteration, but the subsequent calls to getData were happening right away when they should've been delayed based on the timer value I parsed from the html. I was just seeing them scroll by in the console one after each other. I need to call request as I am parsing the html to find the product to display and to set the timeout interval. But its as if the I'm doing `setTimeout(getData(url),0)`

Comment: Because your request is executing immediately.  Look at the code I posted -- you need a function as the target of `setTimeout` that will execute once the timeout finishes.  You did not have that; you were trying to do both with a single function.